# CREATE FOREIGN TABLE with a variable NameInSource

Tags: sql-server, variables

Is it possible to define a variable in the `NameInSource` when defining a foreign table?

The SQL Server we use has 2 database names for 2 environments within the same SQL Server instance.

Therefore we have to define something like

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE zaak 
(
    col1 ...,
    col2 ...,
    ...
    coln ...,

    CONSTRAINT ...)
) OPTIONS(NAMEINSOURCE '${databaseName}', UPDATABLE 'TRUE', CARDINALITY '99');
```

...but this is not working.

Is it possible to define a variable in ddl that resolves at deploy-time?

Comment: You can't use a variable to replace a literal no. The only way you would be able to do it would be with dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the dynamic value.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:sql-server]

Comment: At the end we migrated 1 database to another server. 
Now all databases have the same name on every server.